# UIPageViewController sample by using storyboard

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

anybody can show me the UIPageViewController sample by using storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy I just figured it out. Open a new project and instead of selecting single view
 application, just select Page-Based View application and it automatically hook everything up.